# Search for username in textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with looking for a username in a text file so that the user should enter a username that is not already stored in the file.

The text file looks like this:

```
aaa12 aaa12
aaa16 aaa16
iii12 iii12
```

Code:

```
    username=input("Enter a username:")
    with open("users.txt") as openfile:
        for line in openfile:
           for part in line.split():
              if username in part:
                 print("Try again")
```

I don't think it works. Is there any other solutions I could use?

Comment: Spacing issue? Check `username in part.strip()` - remember `\n` is still in the line.

Comment: ok thanks ill check

Comment: I need to make sure that if the username does exist it will ask the ask to re-enter a username until it doesent exist in the file

Answer (score 2):

You can do the `in` (`__contains__`) test directly on the string (`line` here) itself, no need for `split`-ing and making a list:

```
for line in openfile:
    if username in line:               
        print("Try again")
        break
```

---

For white separated username (as shown in the example), and each username is a whole match:

```
for line in openfile:
    if username in line.split():
        print("Try again")
        break
```

---

Note that, matching username is never going to be perfect. If simple matching does not work, then  probably you should think about picking a suitable container first rather than doing text processing.

Comment: What about a user `userusernamename`? `dor` with an existing `dori`?

Comment: @kabanus Matching a name is never full-proof. It seems it should work for OP.

Comment: OP posted something more fool proof - breaking by spaces and comparing is essential here.

Comment: If that is the case, you should use == operator instead of "in" because "in" would check for substring in a string.

Comment: yeah i need to match it otherwise id have two usernames in the same file which would be confusing

Comment: yeah i need to make sure that the user does not enter another username if its in the file

Answer (score 1):

You're rechecking too many times - you were on the way, but I suggest first collecting, then checking:

```
users = set()
with open("users.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        users.update(line.split())
        #Another way:
        #for user in line.split():
            #users.add(user)

first = True
while first or (username in users):
    if not first: print("Try again, exists!")
    username=input("Enter a username:")
    first = False
```

Comment: `strip()` should not be needed, given that the result comes from `split()`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Correct, for some reason I thought it would leave the `\n`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
username=input("Enter a username:")
exists = False
with open("users.txt") as openfile:
  for line in openfile:
   if username in line:
    exists = True

if not exists:
  print("Try again")
```

This would handle if you have usernames in multiple lines in the text file. Basically, you don't need all the hoops of splitting in python, which is a beauty really.

Comment: Wait so how would the file look in my case?

Comment: Your file has multiple lines. So, it is easy if you follow the boolean variable pattern